# UNIX DATE: how to calculate a date

Tags: unix

I'm new at UNIX and I do some exercises and my goal is to get number as parameter - "n"
than calculate the date of today less n

```
(TODAY -N = answer)
```

and the answer will be displayed as

```
date +%a-%b-%d-%Y
```

how do I do it in easy way?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Like this? `$ date -d"-1 month" --> Mon Sep 16 14:44:42 CEST 2013`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about,

```
n=5

date +%a-%b-%d-%Y --date="$n days ago"
```

?

gives `Fri-Oct-11-2013`

Source: [Date manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date)